# Get specific PID and save to file

Tags: grep, awk, ps

I'm running two minecraft servers on my machine. I want to know what the pid is of a single mc server that is running and put it to file so that I can kill it later. So for this example I only want to know what the PID is of World2 nothing else and save it to file.

When I perform a command

```
ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft
```

I get the following results

```
31416 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx2G -Xms1G -jar /data/mc-server/World1/minecraft_server.jar nogui
31706 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx6G -Xms4G -jar /data/mc-server/World2/craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

I then pipe to grep using this command

```
grep World2
```

This is where I get into difficulties, I then pipe to to get a single result back. I tried the following but just can't get it.

```
awk '{print $1 > world2.pid}'
```

So my full command is:

```
ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft | grep World2 | awk '{print $1 > world2.pid}'
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $1 > world2.pid}
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to put the redirection *inside* awk, you need to put the filename in quotes - otherwise, awk treats it as a variable rather than a literal string:

```
... | awk '{print $1 > "world2.pid"}'
```

However it would be more conventional to let awk write to standard output, and redirect *that* i.e.

```
... | awk '{print $1}' > world2.pid
```

Alternatively, you may want to look at using `pgrep` for the whole task e.g. something like

```
pgrep -f 'World2' > world2.pid
```

Comment: I guess `awk '{print $1}'> world.pid` should also work

Comment: @Ron yes indeed - and would be the more conventional syntax I think: I updated the answer to discuss both forms

Answer (score 7):

If you put the `> world2.pid` after `awk '{print $1}'`, it should work:

```
ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft | grep World2 | awk '{print $1}' > world2.pid
```

Then the output of:

```
ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft | grep World2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

is written to:

```
world2.pid
```

**OR**

As suggested (thanks) by @JonathanLeffler, you could save the usage of `grep`:

```
ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft | awk '/World2/ {print $1}' > world2.pid
```

Comment: You don't need `grep` if you use `awk`.  You could use: `ps h -o pid,cmd -u minecraft | awk '/World2/ { print $1 > "world2.pid" }'` instead, or do the I/O redirection in the shell (which is simpler).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very nice! I borrowed the first suggestion :), edited into the answer.